# How do you make sure UX is part of a new web strategy?

Tags: website-design, lean-ux

My company is about to completely redesign our website. We don't yet have end goals in mind that the website must achieve; we're still in the very early phase of creating a brand new web strategy.

I don't have any experience in creating and defining and implementing a web strategy, but since I work in UX and web dev, I want to make sure that UX and the user is a vital part of this new strategy that we create. Not only that, I want to help shape and lead a more agile-approach to UX design and implementation. My company is stuck in a waterfall-like approach to planning, design and implementation, so I want to change that.

How can I do this? Does anyone have any books and/or articles that are must-reads for learning more about creating a web strategy and influencing the creation of the web strategy to always consider the user and his/her needs? Any advice or materials on how to communicate this to management?

My goal from this question is to eventually achieve a firm grasp on (1) creating and guiding a successful web strategy that always keeps content and the user in focus and (2) implementing a more agile UX process to the entire project life cycle vs. a waterfall approach.

Comment: get the book Lean UX; it's short and has reasonable answers to all of the questions. Most importantly, factor in two things (1) the culture of your company and (2) how you can make your bosses look better in the eyes of the other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I churn through these questions one-by-one, this isn't really the "type" of question, as it's very vague. Any number of answers, all mostly opinion-based, could suffice. I'll lay our some generic ones here that answer your questions, though.

- ***Step 1:*** Get end goals in mind that the website must achieve.
- ***How can I do this?*** - You say you have a background in UX and Web Design. Awesome starting point. You know what it takes to develop a website with a strong UX focus - so break that process down into steps.
- ***Books / Articles?*** - Not to be a jerk, but Google it. Keywords include "UX Planning", "UX Workflow", etc.
- ***...about influencing the web strategy/creation of the web strategy/something about user needs*** - You answred your own question. Keep user needs in mind. Ask questions. At every point throughout the process, ***once you have the end-goals on paper***, ask yourself if the design/development choices address these needs.
- ***Advice to comm. this to management?*** - Keep it brief, direct, to the point, and potent. Remove all fluff. Remove buzzwords.
- ***Entire bottom paragraph*** - More organically look at the process than just a "successful web strategy that always keeps content and the user in focus". Get your project goals on paper, commit to them, and convey to management that **this is a highly effective way to approach a successful project/product launch**.
- ***Specifically the part about Agile UX process*** - Iterate. Iterate. Iterate. Products are never "truly" done. They need to evolve along with the business, and as such, improvements to the UX need to come with time. The idea of "Agile" UX Design involves the concept of "Iteration". You make a V1, put it into Beta, see how things work. Improve to a V2-#n, until you feel it works well, then launch. This is the "testing" portion. Even after launch, you can have new versions roll out, based on user feedback.

  - That reminds me, *ask for user feedback*. ***A Lot.***